# unity 4.6.2 Serial.IO.Ports

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to use Arduino UNO in a project. As I understood, I need to use Serial.IO.Ports.
The problem is that this library desn't semm to exist in the free version of Unity.

As purchasing the pro version isn't an option, is there a way around ? Or I am just missing something ?

In case there is nothing to do, does another free game engine allows the use of Arduino ?

Thank you for your help,

JB

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question can be found here :

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-change-the-net-framework-version-of-the-unity.128831/